# What stable c++11 feature can be used safely

Tags: c++, c++11

What are the `C++11` features that have got enough mature that I can start using safely in my projects. I am talking about `GCC` mainly I rarely need Visual Studio. and I obviously don't want to include a feature in my code that requires a rewrite after few months. and should I even start using these features in this very beginning ?  cause whatever we mostly do is not `c++11 dependent` we can do all things and every things in old school methods too. so should we even start using C++11 features at this early stage ?

Comment: What GCC version are you targeting, where will this code run, what do your target systems use... This page details when features were available in GCC versions: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: I am using MinGW on Windows I'vent checked that version . and On Linux I've 4.3.2 however I donno Where I'll be placed next time for work.

Comment: are those features open to changes ? or they are stable ?

Comment: they are stable and usable, also another link that details implementation completeness across major compilers: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport - there was a time when a lot of those entries in GCC were 'no' or 'partial'. If there is a version number there it means the particular C++11 feature is considered production-ready and stable enough for use. Though with GCC 4.3 you are pretty limited in what C++11 features you have access to.

Comment: Another important detail is how your code is released. If you build your code against your GCC 4.3.2 ( or GCC 4.4, 4.5, etc.), and only release binaries, you have to remember that target platforms have their own set of C++ libraries (i.e. libstdc++.so for GCC), and if they are older than the version you compiled for, your programs almost assuredly won't work.

Comment: If you are that worried about it, waiting is the only sensible precaution. You appear to already know the answers to all your questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++11 standard is finally done and published, so there won't be any more changes. Implementations still lag behind a little and may implement slightly older versions of C++0x, but you probably won't notice much difference when they are updated.

C++11 isn't perfectly backwards compatible, so the first thing you should do is start developing with C++11 compatibility in mind. GCC has a warning flag, "-Wc++0x-compat", to help with this. The incompatibilities are pretty small but this should turn up anything that will be a problem.

One large incompatibility is that libstdc++'s ABI changes with the move to C++11, so you'll also have to make sure you can deal with that.

Once you know it's safe to move over, just start building in C++11 mode. You can gradually adopt whatever C++11 features seem useful to you as you write new code or change old code. You might want to also consider checking for uses of deprecated functionality, such as the old exception specifications, and replace those with the new stuff.

There's a lot of new stuff so have a look through the standard if you can get it or some documentation online. I find that most of the really interesting stuff I want to use directly is in the library. Unfortunately that seems to be where current implementations still lag the most.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to visit:

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

This link gives the C++0x Support in different GCC versions.

I suggest you use C++11 now (just adding -std=c++0x into the GCC command line). If you were lucky, then nothing would be changed in your code. Even if you do not use any C++11 features, you may still benefit from performance improvements coming from the rvalue references and move semantics.